# How to create rows with dates for school class attendance?

Tags: mysql

I want to generate a table for keeping school class attendance in MySQL.  What are MySQL approaches with joins, inserts, etc. that can simplify the creation of this attendance table?

I have included a table representing the schedule below (see Table 1). Each row in the schedule includes information on the class, student, days of the week, and class times.  It currently has 830 rows.

Others have approached similar problems by creating a calendar table of dates which I have represented as Table 2.

```
// Table 1: classSchedule   <---- Starting table
scheduleID  class      studentID    days    startTime   endTime
1           Biology    A123456      MWF     10:30       12:00
2           Math       A123456      MTWRF   09:30       10:30
3           English    A123456      MW      13:00       14:30
...

// Table 2: schoolCalendar   <----  Table of dates
calendarID  date          dayOfWeek    dayNumber
...
11          2019-07-15    M            1
12          2019-07-16    T            2
13          2019-07-17    W            3
14          2019-07-18    R            4
15          2019-07-19    F            5
...

// Table 3: classAttendance   <----- Desired table
attendanceID   scheduleID   date            day  attendanceCode
1              1            2019-07-15      M    P
2              1            2019-07-17      W
3              1            2019-07-19      F
4              1            2019-07-22      M
5              1            2019-07-24      W
6              1            2019-07-26      F
...
```

I would like the class attendance schedule to look similar to Table 3.  Each row will represent a single class on a unique date and time.  It should include a column for the schedule ID so I can delete or update the classAttendance table when there are updates to the classSchedule table.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Do you have a specific question? Otherwise, this seems a little too broad for SO. Incidentally, if I was going to do table 1 like (i.e. not having a separate table for days), then I think I'd store days as an integer (M=1,M-F =31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using an "INSERT INTO SELECT" and an "INNER JOIN".  The critical aspect is the use of an IF statement in the INNER JOIN that checks whether the class occurs on a given day of the week.  It uses an IF statement of this form:

IF(condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)

```
IF(POSITION(SchoolCalendar.day in classScheduleTest.days)>0,SchoolCalendar.day,'')
```

This IF statement produces output like this:

```
classScheduleTest.days    SchoolCalendar.day     Output
MTWRF                     M                      M
TR                        M                      
MWF                       W                      W
...
```

The MySQL statement to produce the ClassAttendance table looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO ClassAttendance 
(ClassAttendance.classScheduleIndex,
 ClassAttendance.className,
 ClassAttendance.studentID,
 ClassAttendance.classDate,
 ClassAttendance.day)
SELECT classScheduleTest.classScheduleIndex,
classScheduleTest.className,
classScheduleTest.studentID,
SchoolCalendar.classDate,
SchoolCalendar.day
FROM classScheduleTest
INNER JOIN SchoolCalendar on IF(POSITION(SchoolCalendar.day in classScheduleTest.days)>0,SchoolCalendar.day,'') = SchoolCalendar.day
WHERE SchoolCalendar.classDate BETWEEN '2019-07-18' AND '2019-07-30'
```

I included a WHERE condition to limit the attendance log to a range of dates.  A sample of the resulting output looks like this:

```
classAttendanceID   classScheduleIndex  className   studentID   classDate   day
1117    2   Math    A12345678   2019-07-18  R   
1118    1   Biology A12345678   2019-07-19  F   
1119    2   Math    A12345678   2019-07-19  F   
1120    1   Biology A12345678   2019-07-22  M   
1121    2   Math    A12345678   2019-07-22  M
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ATTENDANCE TABLE

attendanceID  BIGINT UNSIGNED , -- you wound defenitely need that
scheduleID INT , -- schedule id
studentID INT --  student
date_attended -- simple date record
attendanceCode   varchar(20)  -- just a sample
```

When it comes to day.  You can just use MySQL  date_format()  function to help you get:

- day of week
- week of year
- day of month
- month of the year

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

read this.